# How to search for Bower packages that depend on another package?

Tags: bower

I would like to do a search for bower packages that depend on another bower package.  For example, I might want to search for bower packages related to "json directive" that depend on the angular package.   How can this be done if at all?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to search in locally installed packages
go to your local bower_components (the place you install bower packages)
and run:

```
grep -Hnri '"<package name>":' ./**/bower.json
```

for example:

```
➜  bower_components# grep -Hnri '"font-roboto":' ./**/bower.json 
./paper-styles/bower.json:25:    "font-roboto": "PolymerElements/font-roboto#^1.0.1",
```

If you would like to do it for all bower packages in http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages 
then you need to write code that will 
download bower.json 
from repository of every component and all versions of this component
and search it for package that you are looking for
(it will take a lot of time)

you could also try something faster and play with github search:
https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=font-roboto+language%3AJSON&type=Code&ref=searchresults